# How to read lines with different format(exceptions) in Lambda function (python code) which reads from S3 to ElK?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, logging, aws-lambda, elastic-stack

**Example Format of my Log file**

-------------------------------------------------------------Start of Log file Format----------------------------------------

```
2020-08-14 05:35:48.752 - [INFO] - from [Class:com.webservices.services.impl.DataImpl Method:bData] in 20 - Data Single completed in 1047  mili sec

2020-08-14 05:35:48.752 - [INFO] - from [Class:com.webservices.services.impl.DataImpl Method:bData] in 20 - Data Single completed in 1099  mili sec

2020-08-14 05:35:48.762 - [ERROR] - from [Class:com.webservices.helper.THelper Method:lambda$0] in 20 - Parsing Response from server Failed

org.json.JSONException: No value for dataModel

at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355) ~[android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1]
```

-----------------------------------------------------------------------End of Log file format ------------------------------

I am currently handling data (with bad coding practice) which starts with a date in the first 3 lines of the log above.

The problem starts with 4th line onward where I have exceptions in my log file with no date. Actually The previous line has the date and its the continuation of the Exception.

I do not know how to handle those lines as the format changes. I wanted to get the date of the previous line for the exception line.

Either I have to keep the previous line's date in a temporary variable and use it if there is format change or any other way.

I need Date as mandatory to push in ELK which takes the timestamp for the log.

Also if there is a suggestion for clean code please do it. I need the lambda to run faster.

**Currently this is my logic in python code (I am a complete beginner in Python code).**

```
import boto3
import botocore
import re
import json
import requests

... 
...

def handler(event, context):
    print("Starting handler function")
    for record in event['Records']:

        # Get the bucket name and key for the new file
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        print("Bucket name - " + bucket)
        print(date_time)
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        print("key name - " + key)
        # Get, read, and split the file into lines
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        body = obj['Body'].read()
        lines = body.splitlines()
        
        # Match the regular expressions to each line and index the JSON
        for line in lines:
             document = {}
             try:
                 if line[0] == '2':
                     listOfData = line.split(" - ")
                     date = datetime.strptime(listOfData[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                     timestamp = date.isoformat()
                     level = listOfData[1]
                     classname = listOfData[2]
                     message = listOfData[-1]
                     document = { "timestamps": timestamp, "level": level, "classnames": classname, "messages": message }
                     print(document)
                 else:
                     document = {"messages": line}
             except ClientError as e:
                 raise e
             r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)
             print(r)
```

Additional Info :
As suggested in the answer by Ben, when i print this_line , i get all lines in the log file printed properly in separate lines but there is a problem for the exception lines in between. below is what printed.

```
{'line content': ['2020-08-14 05:35:48.762 - [ERROR] - from [Class:com.webevics.helpr.Helpr Method:lamda] in 2 - Parsng Respns from servr Failed', 'org.jsn.JSONExcepion: No vlue for dataModel'], 'date string': '2020-08-14 05:35:47.655'}
{'line content': ['2020-08-14 05:35:48.762 - [ERROR] - from [Class:com.webserics.helpr.Helpr Method:lambda] in 2 - Parsing Respnse from servr Faied', 'org.jsn.JSONException: No vlue for dataModel', 'at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355) ~[android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1]'], 'date string': '2020-08-14 05:35:47.655'}
```

Here i am getting 2 lines printed where the first line is useless and 2nd line is better . So can we make something like the 1st line should not come and only the 2nd line is present in this_line ?

Comment: share the file structure pls

Comment: Balderman : It is already shared above

Answer (score 0):

I started by placing your sample data in a file,

```
2020-08-14 05:35:48.752 - [INFO] - from [Class:com.webservices.services.impl.DataImpl Method:bData] in 20 - Data Single completed in 1047 mili sec

2020-08-14 05:35:48.752 - [INFO] - from [Class:com.webservices.services.impl.DataImpl Method:bData] in 20 - Data Single completed in 1099 mili sec

2020-08-14 05:35:48.762 - [ERROR] - from [Class:com.webservices.helper.THelper Method:lambda$0] in 20 - Parsing Response from server Failed

org.json.JSONException: No value for dataModel

at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355) ~[android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1]

2020-08-14 05:35:48.752 - [INFO] - from [Class:com.webservices.services.impl.DataImpl Method:bData] in 20 - Data Single completed in 1099 mili sec
```

I've added a fourth entry just to verify my approach works. The Python below detects the start of a line using a regular expression tailored to the date format

```
import re
with open('example.txt','r') as file_handle:
    file_content = file_handle.read().split("\n")
    
list_of_lines = []
this_line = {}
for index, line in enumerate(file_content):
    if len(line.strip())>0:
        reslt = re.match('\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d{3}', line)
        if reslt: # line starts with a date
            if len(this_line.keys())>0:
                list_of_lines.append(this_line)
            date_string = reslt.group(0)
            this_line = {'date string':date_string, 'line content': []}
            this_line['line content'].append(line)
        else:
            this_line['line content'].append(line)
```

The data structure produced, `list_of_lines`, is a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary is an error entry which may contain one or more lines. The two keys in the error dictionary are `date string` and `line content`.

To review the output data structure, try running

```
for line in list_of_lines[2]['line content']:
    print(line)
```

Comment: in the else part this_line keeps appending even old lines in a single line with comma separated. 
if there are 3 lines of exception all 3 lines are appended to one line and 3 lines are printed instead of one. can u help me with that ?

Comment: I'd be happy to help. Can you edit your question and provide additional sample data showing what you mean?  Or are you experiencing the issue you're describing with the 4 entries I'm using in my answer?

Comment: I have edited the Question with Additional info at the end. Kindly check it Ben

Comment: You mentioned in your additional info that "the first line is useless and 2nd line is better." Can you clarify what makes the first line useless? Also, why is the second line better? Could you provide an example data structure of what you're seeking for the desired output?

Comment: First line is useless because the same line is repeated in the 2nd line with additional data. So I Can make use of 2nd line and the first line has to be ignored anyway.